# Macro to hardcode rows subject to a value in column A of each row

Tags: vba, loops

I am new to VBA and I am stuck!

I am trying to write a macro that will search through column A of my worksheet, and then if it finds a "1" then it will hardcode that row.

I have the below which I found online and adapted, but it only works where column A contains hardcoded values of 1 or 0.  In reality my column A is a formula the output of which is 1 or 0.

Is there a simple way to fix the below so that the code can react to a formula output of 1 rather than just a hardcoded input of 1?

```
Sub formulatovalue()

ActiveSheet.Select

Dim c As Range

For Each c In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)

If c.Value = "1" Then

c.EntireRow.Value = c.EntireRow.Value

End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: `.SpecialCells(xlConstants)` is telling it to only look at constants (hardcoded).  Remove that bit to have it look at all cells, or use `xlCellTypeFormulas` to look at formula cells.  Also `"1"` (naturally right aligned) will tell it to look for the string value of "1" which will exclude the numeric value 1 (naturally left aligned).  Use `If c.Value = 1 Then`

Comment: Is there a way to get this macro to then run automatically whenever a formula in column A outputs "1"    (rather than manually activating the macro)